# SQL expression for finding strings including letters in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, arcgis-9.3

I'm working on ArcGIS 9.3.1. I have a shapefile with a string field containing point names like these:

```
10
12
12/13
t/9
6577y
1234
12t9
124y67
u9
```

and so on (and yes, I know it looks like a colossal mess. It's not my design). Using  `WHERE MyColumn LIKE '%Search String%'` I can find (using select by attribute) the ones containing a specific letter or a backslash (/).

How can I select all values containing a letter (in this example: t/9, 6577y, 12t9, 124y67, u9), not caring what letter it is or it's position? (is there a way to specify a position?)

Comment: You sure you didn't just slam your head on your keyboard and pop that out? :P

Comment: unfortunately, NO.

Answer (score 2):

For something quick and (very) dirty, you could use something like this to find all the records with any of the standard 26-letter alphabet characters. Use find and replace in your favorite text editor to change the `MyColumn` name to your real column name.

```
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%A%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%B%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%C%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%D%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%E%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%F%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%G%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%H%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%I%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%J%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%K%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%L%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%M%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%N%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%O%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%P%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%Q%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%R%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%S%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%T%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%U%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%V%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%W%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%X%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%Y%') OR
UPPER("MyColumn") LIKE('%Z%')
```

For anything more complex I would instead use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expressions) in a [SearchCursor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000039000000.htm) in Python (see the [`re` module](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/re.html)), or put the data in a real database and use its specific string searching capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

Convert to a personal geodatabase.

Wildcards:

- question mark `?` = any alpha character
- pound sign `#` = any numeric character

[pointname] like "12?"  should return 12A, 12b, 12c and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider adding an integer column to your shapefile, calling it "MATCH".  Then use the [field calculator](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Making_field_calculations) to perform string matching tests in a pre-logic code block.
After the Match field is populated, you may then select on it using the Select by attributes tool.

Side note: It's been a long time but it seemed like INFO supported a pseudo column (was it $RECSEL ?) that allowed you to select things using a CALCULATE command.  This use case points out a situation where something like that would be helpful.  IMO, Esri should enhance the field calculator to support pseudo columns for selection. The field calculator would present a boolean target field when the user right clicks on the unlabeled block next to the left most column's field header.

Update: If you agree, please [vote for my idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000brQN).

[image]

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "string matching tests in a pre-logic code block" ???

Comment: In the field calculator click the "show codeblock" checkbox.  You should then be able to use VBA string manipulation functions.  Don't get too carried away though, VBA goes away at 10.0. See [this KB article](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/31807).

Answer (score 0):

If your data is on MS-SQL try ranges within search exressions like

`... where col like '%[a-z]%'`

or a number afer a string with any one character between:

`... where col like '%[a-z]_[0-9]%'

If you need to look for a '-' put it at the beginning of the search string like

`... where col like '%[-a-z0-9]%'`

would match '-' or a letter or a number